# UWP Application - Internal Server could not access via VPN

Tags: uwp, window

We are working on the UWP application created using the Cordova windows. The application works perfectly if we connect the external server host.

Issue :
If I try to connect the "Internal Server" using VPN, it does not connect. If I run the Fiddler in background, it connects to the internal server but I could not ask customer to run the fiddler every time in the background.

Edited On Nov 06,2020:
If we have disabled IPv6 property on the systems, the application starts to connect internal server address. Any specific Reasons?

Do I need to any configuration inside the UWP application?

Comment: I assumed "starts to connect" actually means "connects". If it means something else, please edit your question.

Comment: Yes..  via Fiddler it connects, without fidder it does not connect.

Comment: Please confirm that have you [enabled the local loopback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/develop-your-app/loopback#enabling-loopback-for-a-uwp-application)?

Comment: Do we need to enable this local loopback in app installing machine or build taking machine or server ? Please confirm.

Comment: I have tried in loopback in mehanisham in app installing machine but it does not work. It does not connect the VPN machine